# Bernoulli's theorem be applied to Laminar flow? But Laminar flow can be non-viscious as well right?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow, bernoulli-equation

I find this contradictory. In my high school Physics book it says that Bernoulli's theorem applies to incompressible, non-viscious fluid having streamline and irrotational flow.

Then it says that Laminar flow can be viscious or non-viscous.

Later on, in the questions section, it states the Bernoulli's theorem applies in Laminar flow.

But Laminar flow *can* be viscious right? And Bernoulli's theorem does not work in viscious fluids. I think a clearer answer would've been that "Bernoulli's theorem can apply in non-viscious Laminar flow". But is my book wrong?